# How to convert the two columns to formal columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a project which counts the total number of crimes in each neighbourhood of San Francisco, I have used the following code, but it does not recognize the neighbourhood column as a column when I try to verify it using crime_counts.dtypes

```
import pandas as pd 
file_name='https://cocl.us/sanfran_crime_dataset'
df=pd.read_csv(file_name)
crime_count = df["PdDistrict"].value_counts().to_frame('C').rename_axis('Neighbourhood')
crime_count = crime_count.rename(columns = {"PdDistrict":"Neighbourhood"})
crime_count = crime_count.rename(columns = {"C":"Counts"})
crime_count
```

I want to create a dataframe, which recognizes both Neighbourhood and Counts as columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change index name by `rename_axis` and then convert `Series` to 2 columns `DataFrame` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with parameter `name`:

```
crime_count = (df["PdDistrict"].value_counts()
                               .rename_axis('Neighbourhood')
                               .reset_index(name='Counts'))
print (crime_count)
  Neighbourhood  Counts
0      SOUTHERN   28445
1      NORTHERN   20100
2       MISSION   19503
3       CENTRAL   17666
4       BAYVIEW   14303
5     INGLESIDE   11594
6       TARAVAL   11325
7    TENDERLOIN    9942
8      RICHMOND    8922
9          PARK    8699
```